# What's the point of the \Users\Default profile?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-profiles

I'm a linux user and don't really know all that much about Windows stuff. I'm changing the default \Users directory and I see that there's a Default user profile at \User\Default that's a hidden link or something. What's the point of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating new users copies that data into the users' profiles, therefore it's the "default" settings etc. [Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2009/10/29/configuring-default-user-settings-full-update-for-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973289/en-us) are articles about these defaults.

Comment: It's exactly like the `/etc/skel` directory in *NIX.